# Material Design Dialog Position in WPF/XMAL

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design, material-design-in-xaml

I am using Material design dialog to show a large message in my wpf application. But when I show it on button chick event it appear at the middle of the application. I want to show it at the bottom of left corner. How do I achieve it? Here is my code

```
 <materialDesign:DialogHost Panel.ZIndex="566" x:Name="mainWindowDialogHost">
    <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
        <Border Height="500" Width="200">
           //here goes a very large message
        </Border>
    </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is actually something independent of Material Design. You can set the `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` properties for all tools. If it is still not exactly in the position you want, you can position it better with the `Margin` feature.

My advice is to split the project design well with tools like Grid, Stackpanel, Dockpanel. In this way, the screen resolution, shrinking and growing will not affect the design.

You can find more detailed information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/grid-tutorial).

```
        <materialDesign:DialogHost Panel.ZIndex="566" x:Name="mainWindowDialogHost" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
            <Border Height="500" Width="200">
                //here goes a very large message
            </Border>
        </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
    </materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

Comment: Have you checked it before putting this answer here. Do you have any idea about dialoghost?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood. Do you want to show the button that opens DialogHost in the lower left corner?

Comment: your answer will work if I put height width of dialog host. But I want full height width of dialog host and it's content to left bottom corner.

Comment: I'll edit the answer if you can help me understand the problem. Do you want to see the button that opens DialogHost in the lower left corner? Or do you want to see the Border in the lower left corner when DialogHost opens.

Comment: You are right I want the border to the lower left corner

Comment: When I check it the border appears in the lower left corner. The problem is if it overflows ? I don't understand why the height of the screen is important.